# How to structure Maui apps so that I can have a master-slave(detail) approach within a shell navigation

Tags: navigation, maui

I have suddenly hit what seems to be an architectural impasse for what I thought would be a simple approach when using dot net Maui.

So the default approach is a shell app. Fair enough and meets my needs well.

However within one Page that I navigate to from the shell flyout menu I display a list of items in an ObservableCollection-xaml CollectionView. I can tap on an item and that should display a detail page.

I had naively thought that there would be a simple navigation function that would allow me to navigate to the detail page, do what I need to and then return to my list page.

In the docs I noted this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage

```
 Warning

NavigationPage is incompatible with .NET MAUI Shell apps, and an exception will be 
thrown if you attempt to use NavigationPage in a Shell app. For more information 
about Shell apps, see Shell.
```

Well that is pants! I want the best of both worlds.

Any thoughts suggestions, work arounds,  ideas? I am not going to recreate the shell, but I need to be able to navigate to a detail page where I will be allowing viewing and editing of selected item data.

Historical note: I was doing this kind of thing quite happily in 1985 using dBase II on an IBM compatible (Sirius) machine using just 5 1/4 inch floppy disks and 128k ram. (10MHz clock?) Surely I can still do it in 2022!! ;)

Comment: you can still use modal navigation for the detail page.  I haven't played with Shell much, but I think you can still navigate to list and detail pages using Routes, just not explicitly with NavigationPage.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#perform-navigation

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that :) All I have to now is figure it out ;)

Comment: It was quite easy, just followed the docs. I think the docs could put in a link to the shell navigation rather than scaring me!! ;)